# Is an arbitrary constant also a variable?

Tags: logic

To motivate the discussion, I'll write down a proof of a result in elementary set theory:

Theorem: If for all constant functions  $f$ such that $\ f \circ g = g \circ f \ $, then $g$ must be the identity map.

Proof: Since $f$ is constant, we can write $\ f(x)=c$ for all $x$, with $c$ being an **arbitrary constant**. Now $ \ f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) \implies c = g(c) \ $. *Since $c$ was arbitrary, it follows that $g$ is the identity map*.

This trick is also used when doing induction in two or more variables, say $m$ and $n$. We induct on, say, $n$, and assume $m$ to be constant. Then at the end of the proof, say write since "$m$ was arbitrary..."

Intuitively, it's pretty obvious, that our arbitrary constant can be assumed to be a variable, but how do I rigorously show that this can always be done?

Comment: To correct the theorem you would want to say "if for all constant functions $f$ such that ...".  Of course, this would be the same as saying "if for all $c$, we let $f(x) = c$ and we have ..."  Universal quantification can be understood as extending the signature with a new (distinct) constant and then reasoning with this extended signature.  In symbols, $$\frac{\Gamma \vdash_{\Sigma,c} P(c) \qquad c \notin \Sigma}{\Gamma \vdash_{\Sigma} \forall x.P(x)}$$

Comment: (Deleted my original observation)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally happy with the statement of your theorem. You should be very precise in what you want, in particular you should take care of the order in which you formulate things. The theorem can be better stated as follows:

Suppose that $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that for any constant function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have that $f\circ g=g\circ f$, then $g$ is the identity.

Proof: Choose $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:x\mapsto c$. Then $g(c)=g(f(c))=f\circ g(c)=c$. Hence for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $g(c)=c$, thus $g=Id$.

So the statement of theorem is of the form $(\exists g: \forall f: f\circ g= g\circ f)\Rightarrow g=Id$.

Comment: Indeed.  The crux of this is scoping.